# Understanding Maxwell relations by considering the differential changes of the enthalpy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In my book it talks about deriving the Maxwell relations and how they can be obtained by considering the differential changes of the enthalpy. By doing this from $$H=U+PV$$ we get $$dH=TdS+VdP$$ and from equation $$U=-PV+H$$ we get $$dU=-PdV+TdS$$ My question is why is it for $dH=TdS+VdP$ its $VdP$ and not $PdV$ and similarly for $U=-PV+H$ why is it $-PdV$ and not $-VdP$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $\mathrm d PV=V\,\mathrm dP+ P\,\mathrm dV$

Comment: See also: [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) and [What is the physical significance of free energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/726612/47360).

Answer (score 2):

The starting point is the fundamental differential $$dU = T dS - P dV\tag{1}$$ This is a fundamental result in thermodynamics and is obtained by combining the first and second law on a closed system undergong reversible process.

For enthalpy start with $H=U+PV$ and take its differential:
$$dH = dU + P dV + V dP$$ Applying (1) we obtain $$\boxed{dH = T dS + V dP}$$